# Shading entries in Hilbert-matrix in TikZ-matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-matrix

I am trying to display a Hilbert-matrix and to color the antidiagonals by varying colors choosen from an array, so that cell (i,j) gets color `\Colors[i+j-1 mod 3]` (so in order that nearby cells with equal value get the same color). The coloring on the Hilbert-matrix I got does not work (yet).

I tried to follow ([Changing color in foreach using arrayjob](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283934/changing-color-in-foreach-using-arrayjob))
but I can't figure out, how to compute the color in fashion that I can use it later in the draw-command.

I tried to define it by use of `execute at begin cell`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\Colors}{{%
"FF0000","00FF00","0000FF",%
%"FF0000","00FF00","0000FF",
}}

%hilbert matrix
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mygridmatrix/.style={matrix of nodes,
    nodes={rectangle,
      draw,
      execute at begin cell=\pgfmathsetmacro{\thecurrentcolor}{\Colors[\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn]}\definecolor{currentcolor}{HTML}{\thecurrentcolor},
      fill=currentcolor,
      minimum width=8mm,
      minimum height=8mm,
      node contents={$\frac{1}{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow+\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1}$},
    },
    nodes in empty cells,
},
]

\matrix (m) [mygridmatrix]
{
&&&\\
&&&\\
&&&\\
&&&\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but this yields only `! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color 'currentcolor'.` :(
Replacing `currentcolor` by any real color like `red` makes it working, but then all antidiagonals get the color (and not the ones according to `\Colors`-array).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the color code supposed to be but you can modify the following accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
  mycolorstyle/.code={%
    \pgfmathparse{\Colors[\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1]}%
    \definecolor{temp}{HTML}{\pgfmathresult}%
    \tikzset{fill=temp}%
  }
}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\Colors}{{"FF0000","00FF00","0000FF","FF0000","00FF00","0000FF"}}

%hilbert matrix
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mygridmatrix/.style={matrix of nodes,
    nodes={rectangle,
      draw,
      mycolorstyle,
      minimum width=8mm,
      minimum height=8mm,
      node contents={$\frac{1}{\pgfmathparse{int(\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow+\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1)}\pgfmathresult}$},
    },
    nodes in empty cells,
},
]
\matrix (m) [mygridmatrix]
{
&&&\\
&&&\\
&&&\\
&&&\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Your version didn't work because `at begin cell` is invoked inside the node's hbox not in the creation of the node shape itself hence it's too late to change the fill spec.

Comment: Thanks! with your help i was able to achieve the antidiagonals by:        \tikzset{
      mycolorstyle/.code={%
        \pgfmathparse{Mod((\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow)+(\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)-1,3)}%
        \pgfmathparse{\Colors[\pgfmathresult]}%
        \definecolor{temp}{HTML}{\pgfmathresult}%
        \tikzset{fill=temp}%
      }
    }