# TikZ: Get colour from an array and use it for drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, indexing, arrayjob

Using the `arrayjob` package, I am able to extract strings from an array and, for example, get *TikZ* to print that text:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{arrayjob}
\newarray\colours
\readarray{colours}{red&orange&yellow&green&blue&purple}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i in {1,2,5} {
            \draw (0,\i) node{\colours(\i)};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I want to colour lines with variable colours in the same way. Naively, I try the following code, which does not work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{arrayjob}
\newarray\colours
\readarray{colours}{red&orange&yellow&green&blue&purple}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i in {1,2,5} {
            \draw[\colours(\i)] (0,\i)--++(1,0);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is a toy example to illustrate what I want. There are obvious ways to do this in this small example, but not my application. I want to extract the colour from an array by index and use that colour to colour the lines.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to SebGlav, I got something working. I'll leave that as an answer down below. There are three good solutions in the answers now, thank you everyone!

Comment: I strongly recommend you to read very carefully [this absolutely comprehensive answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283937/204164) from egreg about that. Don't use `arrayjob` with LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you @SebGlav, I figured it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested, using the array functionality of Ti*k*Z you can get:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{arrayjob}
%\newarray\colours
%\readarray{colours}{red&orange&yellow&green&blue&purple}
\def\mycolours{{"red","orange","yellow","green","blue","purple"}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \usecolor using {\mycolours[\i]}]in {1,2,5} {
            \draw[color=\usecolor] (0,\i)--++(1,0);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this one the best. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

pgfkeys can be your array

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\pgfkeys{
    /benis/.cd,
    1/.initial=red,
    2/.initial=orange,
    3/.initial=yellow,
    4/.initial=green,
    5/.initial=blue,
    6/.initial=purple,
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i in {1,2,5} {
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/benis/\i}\thiscolor
            \draw (\i,\i/2)node[circle,draw=\thiscolor]{\thiscolor};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for a nice use of `pgfkeys `

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to SebGlav, I got something working. I have to type the RGB codes for the colours I want, but that's fine. This code works:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\colours}{{"FF0000","FFA500","FFFF00","008000","0000FF","800080"}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i in {1,2,5} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\currentcolour}{\colours[\i]}
            \definecolor{currentcolour}{HTML}{\currentcolour}
            \draw[currentcolour] (0,\i)--++(1,0);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Array operations of TeX (hence, TikZ) is quite inconvernient. A simple use of arrays of numbers, texts (including colors), points (as pairs of 2 coordinates) is as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

% array of numbers a[i], i=0,1,2,3
\def\a{{6,8,11,12}}

% array of texts b[i], i=0,1,2,3
\def\b{{"blue","red","orange","teal"}}

% array of points (coordinates) c[i], i=0,1,2,3
\def\c{{"(1,2)","(1.5,1.5)","(3,2.5)","(5,3)"}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,.5) rectangle (6.5,3.5);
\foreach \i in {0,...,3}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ii}{int(\i+1)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpa}{\a[\i]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpb}{\b[\i]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpc}{\c[\i]}
\path (0,-\i) node[right,\tmpb,align=left]
{The \ii-th element is $\tmpa{}$ with \tmpb{} color\\
associated with the point $\tmpc$};
\fill[\tmpb] \tmpc node[above]{\tmpa} circle(2pt);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried a lot of array stuff I found online and was getting frustrated. All these comments are great. Thanks!